# Show that a given sigma field is the smallest one containing the given class of sets

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

I've been trying to solve the following question from Leo Breiman, Probability but getting stuck in how to proceed and have few doubts as well.

Define $\mathcal{B}^{(\infty)}$ as the smallest $\sigma$- field containing the rectangles $\{\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots) : x_1 \in I_1,\ x_2 \in I_2,\ldots,x_n \in I_n\}$ where $I_1,I_2,\ldots,I_n$ are intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ for some $n$.

Now define $\mathcal{B}^{(\infty)}(E)$ as the collection of all sets in $\mathcal{B}^{(\infty)}$ that are subsets of $E$. Take E=$\{0,1\}$.

Question:

Prove that $\mathcal{B}^{(\infty)}(\{0,1\})$ is the smallest $\sigma$- field containing all sets of the form 
$$
\{\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots): x_1=s_1,x_2=s_2,\ldots,x_n=s_n\}
$$

where $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ is any $n$-long sequence $\in \{0,1\}^n,\ n=1,2,...$

Firstly, I am unable to prove how $\mathcal{B}^{(\infty)}(E)$ defined above will be a $\sigma$- field. Also why will the above sets lie in $\mathcal{B}^{(\infty)}(\{0,1\})$ ?

Can anyone help me with this ?